# Show $A$ is compact subset of a metric space $(X,\mathscr T, d)$ only if for all $x \in X$, $d(x,A)=d(x,a)$ for some $a \in A$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity, metric-spaces, compactness

Topology by James Munkres Exer27.2b

> [image]

This exercise has been previously asked about, and while some of the proofs are similar or the same as mine, they're outlines left for the reader.

I have 3 proofs which I guess are either wrong or inelegant. **Please point out and explain any errors in them.** I put the propositions cited at the end.

The outlines of my proofs are as as follows:

1. Outline of Pf 1: The set $\{d(x,a)\}_{a \in A}$ is a compact subspace of $\mathbb R$ and thus is closed in $\mathbb R$ and thus has a minimum in $\mathbb R$.
2. Outline of Pf 2: The set $\{d(x,a)\}_{a \in A}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$, deduced without proving it is a compact subspace of $\mathbb R$ and then thus, has a minimum in $\mathbb R$.
3. Outline of Pf 3: The set $\{d(x,a)\}_{a \in A}$ is a compact subspace of $\mathbb R$ and thus has a minimum in $\mathbb R$ without proving it is closed in $\mathbb R$.

The proofs are as follows:

---

(moved to answers)

---

Cor 17.7

> [image]

Exer 18.11

> [image]

Exer 20.3a

> [image]

Thm 26.3

> [image]

Thm 26.5

> [image]

Exer 26.4

> [image]

Exer 26.6

> [image]

Heine Borel Theorem (Thm 27.3)

> [image]

Extreme Value Theorem (Thm 27.4)

> [image]

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Each of your proofs is correct with a small modification: a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has minimum if it is bounded from below. But each of your subsets is obviously bounded from below by $0$.

Comment: @freakish 'Please point out and explain any errors in them. I put the propositions cited at the end.' Thanks a million for reading them all! ^-^ Why don't you post as answer! P.S. Do you use topology in software development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pf 2:

By Exer 20.3(a) and Exer 18.11, for any $x \in X$, the map given by $d': A \to \mathbb R$ s.t. $d'(x,a)=d(x,a)$ is continuous in the variable $a$.

Because $A$ is compact and $\mathbb R$ is Hausdorff, we have by Exer 26.6 that $d'$ is a closed map. Thus, its image, $\{d(x,a)\}_{a \in A}$, is closed in $\mathbb R$.

Therefore $\{d(x,a)\}_{a \in A}$ contains its limit points by Cor 17.7 including its infimum, $d(x,A)$, as a minimum, namely, $d(x,a^{*})$ for some $a^{*} \in A.$

Thanks to freakish: $\{d(x,a)\}_{a \in A}$ is bounded below by $0$ and is closed, and therefore has a minimum, namely its infimum.

QED

Answer (score 0):

Pf 1:

By Exer 20.3(a) and Exer 18.11, for any $x \in X$, the map given by $d': A \to \mathbb R$ s.t. $d'(x,a)=d(x,a)$ is continuous in the variable $a$.

Because $A$ is compact, we have that by Thm 26.5, $d'$s image, $\{d(x,a)\}_{a \in A}$, is compact subspace of $\mathbb R$ and thus, is closed by any of the following:

- Heine Borel Theorem (Thm 27.3)
- Thm 26.3
- Exer 26.4

Therefore $\{d(x,a)\}_{a \in A}$ contains its limit points by Cor 17.7 including its infimum, $d(x,A)$, as a minimum, namely, $d(x,a^{*})$ for some $a^{*} \in A.$

Thanks to freakish: $\{d(x,a)\}_{a \in A}$ is bounded below by $0$ and is closed, and therefore has a minimum, namely its infimum.

QED

Answer (score 0):

Pf 3:

By Exer 20.3(a) and Exer 18.11, for any $x \in X$, the map given by $d': A \to \mathbb R$ s.t. $d'(x,a)=d(x,a)$ is continuous in the variable $a$.

Because $A$ is compact, we have that by Thm 26.5, $d'$s image, $\{d(x,a)\}_{a \in A}$, is compact subspace of $\mathbb R$.

Therefore, by the (argument that proves the) Extreme Value Theorem (Thm 27.4), $\{d(x,a)\}_{a \in A}$ has a mininum $d(x,a^{*})$ for some $a^{*} \in A$, and this minimum is its equal to its infimum, $d(x,A)$.

Thanks to freakish: $\{d(x,a)\}_{a \in A}$ is bounded below by $0$ and is closed, and therefore has a minimum, namely its infimum.

QED

Comment: In general if $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $Y$ is a non-empty subset of $X$ then $f(x)=\inf \{d(x,y)\}$ is continuous.  In particular, if $a\in X$ then $g(x)=d(x,a)$ is continuous.

Comment: Forgot this already but thanks @DanielWainfleet !